# Cache gems in GitLab CI bundle build

Tags: ruby, caching, docker, bundle, gitlab

I'm using a docker image to run test for a bunch of repositories. Each repository has its own tests and of course its own Gemfile. So, basically, whenever I made a commit to these repositories, a new build starts. In this build, GitLab:

1. Download the docker image.
2. Install all needed gems.
3. Run the tests.

The docker image has some preinstalled packages like ruby or gcc so I don't lose any time reinstalling those packages in each build, but still I have to install all the gems as each repository has its own Gemfile and they are a bit different.

The thing is, what can I do to improve build time? I'm loosing a lot of time with the build install command and most of the time it installing the same packages for every repository over and over.

Comment: Could you post what your .gitlab-ci.yml looks like?

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#caching-ruby-dependencies), example `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: ruby:2.5.1

variables:
  BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/ruby

cache:
  key: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
  paths:
    - vendor/ruby

test:
  script:
    - bundle install -j $(nproc) --path vendor
    - gem install rubocop --no-ri --no-rdoc
    - rubocop

production:
  type: deploy
  script:
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=admin --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  only:
    - master
```

This will add your gems to cache and will re-use it in another build. However, it may not be used when build will be running on the another executor.

Comment: The `--path` flag has been deprecated. Run the command `bundle config set --local path 'vendor'` instead.

Comment: @ClintonBlackburn yes, now `BUNDLE_PATH` env variable is used for this purposes. I've updated the answer with the config I'm using now. Thank you for pointing it and improving the answer

Answer (score -1):

I'm not that familiar with ruby, but in some languages you can have a local cache for installed libraries. If you can do that with ruby, which I'm sure you can. You can store this cache on the host (or a data container) and the mount that cache via volumes into each container.

This is how it will work.

You create the cache and mount it in your container, then you point your ruby app to use this cache when installing gems. If the gem is in the cache, it will get it locally, if not it needs to download it. Now it will be available locally for next time. The local cache should be faster (no download). Since you share the cache across projects it should reduce build time.

Option 2: you create a base image that has all common gems and use that one for your tests. That is harder to keep in sync and results in bloated images.

Comment: Actually the question is about how to configure GitLab CI to cache ruby gems, and refers to documentation — https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#caching-ruby-dependencies